# .NET Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition - MAUI Mobile App

Tags: mobile, sdk, maui, visual-studio-2022

I have installed .NET Visual Studio 2022. SDK 8 is also installed. Whether I open an app that works on another computer or create a new project I am getting the below errors. When I look at the "Dependencies" net8.0-android, ios, maccatalyst, & windows10.0.19041.0.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.52\Sdk\Sdk.targets" was not imported by "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\8.0.100\microsoft.net.sdk.android\34.0.52\WorkloadManifest.targets" at (3,5), due to the file not existing.    MyFirstMAUIApp  C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.52\Sdk\Sdk.targets 3
Error       Project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\17.0.8490\Sdk\Sdk.props" was not imported by "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\8.0.100\microsoft.net.sdk.ios\17.0.8490\WorkloadManifest.targets" at (3,3), due to the file not existing.  MyFirstMAUIApp  C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\17.0.8490\Sdk\Sdk.props 3
Error       Project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Windows.Sdk\17.0.8490\Sdk\Sdk.props" was not imported by "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\8.0.100\microsoft.net.sdk.ios\17.0.8490\WorkloadManifest.targets" at (5,3), due to the file not existing.  MyFirstMAUIApp  C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Windows.Sdk\17.0.8490\Sdk\Sdk.props 5
Error       Project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Sdk\17.0.8490\Sdk\Sdk.props" was not imported by "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\8.0.100\microsoft.net.sdk.maccatalyst\17.0.8490\WorkloadManifest.targets" at (3,3), due to the file not existing.  MyFirstMAUIApp  C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Sdk\17.0.8490\Sdk\Sdk.props 3
Error   NU1012  Platform version is not present for one or more target frameworks, even though they have specified a platform: net8.0-android, net8.0-ios, net8.0-maccatalyst   MyFirstMAUIApp  E:___Development__MyFirstMauiApp\MyFirstMAUIApp\MyFirstMAUIApp.csproj 1
Error   NU1012  Platform version is not present for one or more target frameworks, even though they have specified a platform: net8.0-android, net8.0-ios, net8.0-maccatalyst   MyFirstMAUIApp  E:___Development__MyFirstMauiApp\MyFirstMAUIApp\MyFirstMAUIApp.csproj 1
Error   NU1012  Platform version is not present for one or more target frameworks, even though they have specified a platform: net8.0-android, net8.0-ios, net8.0-maccatalyst   MyFirstMAUIApp  E:___Development__MyFirstMauiApp\MyFirstMAUIApp\MyFirstMAUIApp.csproj 1
Error   NU1012  Platform version is not present for one or more target frameworks, even though they have specified a platform: net8.0-android, net8.0-ios, net8.0-maccatalyst   MyFirstMAUIApp  E:___Development__MyFirstMauiApp\MyFirstMAUIApp\MyFirstMAUIApp.csproj 1
Error   NETSDK1139  The target platform identifier android was not recognized.  MyFirstMAUIApp  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets   117
Error   NETSDK1139  The target platform identifier ios was not recognized.  MyFirstMAUIApp  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets   117
Error   NETSDK1139  The target platform identifier maccatalyst was not recognized.  MyFirstMAUIApp  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets   117

I have uninstalled and reinstalled VS 2022 and SDK 8. The errors will not resolve.

Comment: You may check if all necessary workloads have been installed using [dotnet workload list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-workload-list). And you can use [dotnet workload install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-workload-install) command to install one or more optional workloads.

Comment: By the way, can you successfully create a new default maui project and build it?